# IntelliJ shortcut refactor object to list of objects

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Lets say I have this method signature:

```
public String get(){};
```

Is there any shortcut in IntelliJ to highlight String and surround it with List<> So I can get the following:

```
public List<String> get(){};
```

Comment: Are you so lazy to do it your hand?

Comment: Well you could do a template, and link it to a hotkey, maybe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### You can make your own *Surround* Live Template:

1. Go to `Settings/Preferences > IDE Settings > Live Templates > surround`.
2. Add a new template.
3. Fill in the form

   1. The abbreviation is used to select from the `Surround With` context menu.
   2. The Description will appear in the `Surround With` context menu.
   3. The `$SELECTION$` variable is predefined as, you guessed it, the selected text.
   4. You can add your own variables, such as `$COLL$` to make the template more generic.
   5. Set the `Applicable in...` to all of Java (or you can be more exact if you want).

[image: How to fill out the Live Template dialog]

### To use it:

1. Select text.
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>⌥⌘T</kbd> on Mac

   - The `Surround With` context menu will appear with your new template.
3. Press <kbd>C</kbd> (since that's the first letter of the template's abbreviation) to quickly select the template.

[image: Surround With context menu]

---

- IntelliJ blog post about this feature: ["Surround with..."](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2006/07/surround-with/)

Comment: Nice one, can we link it easily to a specific hotkey?

Comment: your screenshots were from mac right? I am running intellij on linux, the font in editor doesn't look so nice as yours... tried a lot googling... what font do you used and do you have some special java-opts/intellij options set? I just switched from eclipse to intellj two months ago.. the eclipse font rendering is much better I have to say.. (I used monaco anti-aliased in eclipse, it looked great)

Comment: @Fabinout Link the whole action to one hotkey? Maybe, but two key combinations isn't so bad.

Comment: @Kent The screenshots are from a Mac. The font I'm using is Ayuthaya. I like it because it's extremely narrow. Wikipedia says it comes standard with Mac OS X, but is intended for Thai characters; so maybe there's another font with the same Latin characters, who knows. I hope you're enjoying IntelliJ, I couldn't live without it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer and this is how we can create a variable :

[image]